# Problema con servicio de nodejs al descargar

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

tengo el siguiente problema, hice un servicio para descargar un archivo en una carpeta compartida, el servicio funciona bien cuando la ruta es así:

```
fileroute = '//server01/file1/file2/SYS/SYS.OFICIO/8327727012020080301'
name = 'dei-2020-10.pdf'
```

luego hice la unión de la ruta de archivo con el nombre

Asi:

```
completeRoute = fileroute  + '\\' + name;
```

el servicio retorna lo siguiente

```
res.download(completeRoute, name);
```

en este caso todo está bien, la descarga del archivo se genera bien,

el problema es cuando el fileroute es como este:

```
fileRoute= '//server01/file1/dei-2015-29/SYS/SYS.EXPEDIENTE/165530042019015839p.m.'

name = 'dei-2014-2948_F(13)dei-2015-29.pdf'

completeRoute = fileroute  + '\\' + name;
```

el servicio nuevamente retorna la descarga

```
res.download(completeRoute, name);
```

el problema es la union de esta ultima carpeta 165530042019015839p.m. con el contra diagonal \

node me tira el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema parece ser el ./ en la unión del archivo con p.m. con la barra / con el nombre se está creando que la cadena está rota y el node piensa que es otro directorio (local)

podrian ayudarme porfavor la rura que estoy accedienendo es a una carpeta compartida de un servidor windows

Answer (score 1):

Intenta usando el modulo path.

```
const path = require("path");
let completeroute = path.join(fileroute, name);
```

Comment: Creo que ahí es mas de problema de tu ruta, verifica que la ruta este correcta, y si usas windows, asegúrate de usar "C:\\" para rutas que no sean locales, aparte de usar "\\" en cada directorio.